# Button top increase with multiple lines

Tags: android, layout-gravity

Some very very strange behaviour was appearing in my Android application.

I was extending Button to replace the standard. In my own button I set:
- TextAppearence (text 16px, bold..)
- BackgroundDrawable (to an selector that replaced the standard button, that used images of 60px)
- `Gravity: LEFT|CENTER_VERTICAL.`

Whenever the text was enough to make the button have 2 text lines, if it had the property `Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL`, a top padding would appear!

This kept me overflowing and googling for weeks... (set paddingTop, singleLine, and other simple solutions didn't work of course!)

Finally got the solution!!!

```
 @Override
 protected boolean setFrame(int l, int t, int r, int b) {
  int fixedTopSize = 5;
  return super.setFrame(l,fixedTopSize, r, b-t);
 }
```

By overriding this method on the extended Button finally i got it to work without the irritating top padding... still i don't understand why this happens.

Any ideia?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that it was the Gravity of the Layout together with the gravity from the buttons and the weight (i wasn't using weightSum just layout_weight) that was messing the layout.

Very strange but... it was happening.